# Git - moving files to another repo and preserving source

Tags: git

I have one repo named **Repo A**, which contains two projects. The goal is to move **Project B** out of **Repo A**. Someone did  this, but before we could remove dependencies to the old location, other people made commits to the old location of **Project B**. To make matters worse, other people also seem to have added commits to **Repo B/Project B**.

What is the easiest way for me to consolidate these changes all into **Repo B** while preserving history?

Answer (score 1):

This will be tedious, but if conflicts appear they should be easy to resolve.

If the changes are not many:

In Repo A - Project B

1. Lock it down, no more edits. (probably you already have)
2. Identify the commits that were done after the move to Repo B by looking at the output of:

   ```
   git log
   ```

In Repo B - Project B

1. `git cherry-pick commit-hash-from-step-2-above`, sample command:

   ```
   git cherry-pick 22c5679c160c5f64f5f58109fe62be683fc896f4
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This will quickly get you all the changes in one step, but conflict resolution will probably be harder.

If the changes are many, but you have a well defined folder structure where project A is isolated from project B, you'll have:

```
repoA/
  projectA/
  projectB/

repoB/
  projectB/
```

So, you could:

Get all the code from repoA

```
cd repoB
git remote add origin2 url-for-repoA
# I assumed the master branch, could be other.
git pull origin2 master
```

The result will be:

```
repoA/
  projectA/
  projectB/

repoB/
  projectA/
  projectB/ <-- probably with conflicts waiting to be resolved
```

Clean up:

```
cd repoB
git reset --hard HEAD projectA/    
git remote remove origin2
```

result:

```
repoB/
  projectB/ <-- still with conflicts waiting to be resolved
```